# Server side data table in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatable, datatables

I have a server side Data Table without any attribute searching or sorting. And now I want to add these attribute.

According to the searches I have, I have to define variables in my controller like this:

```
   public int Start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]);
```

But my controller does not understand the word `Request`  and gives an error
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Your question seems incomplete and dose not clearly describe that what do you want to achieve. Share your code of Datatable and describe properly what you want to do you want to do with it. Thanks

Comment: What is `Request["start"]` and what kind of data contained inside it? Please give details about your controller action to make sure, provide your [mcve].

Comment: Is your question related with https://datatables.net/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the System.Web assembly in the application?

`using System.Web;`

If not, try specifying the System.Web namespace, for example:

```
 public int Start = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Request["start"]);
```